# If a pandas dataframe has two columns with the same name, np.where seems to break... Is this expected behavior?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy

Here is the example that works:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(10,3),columns=['A','B','C'])
df['D'] = np.nan

for i in range(df.shape[1]-1):
    df['D'] = np.where(df.iloc[:,i] == df.min(axis=1),
                       df.iloc[:,i].shift(-1),
                       df['D'])
df
```

Here is the example that breaks (changing column B by A):

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(10,3),columns=['A','A','C'])
df['D'] = np.nan

for i in range(df.shape[1]-1):
    df['D'] = np.where(df.iloc[:,i] == df.min(axis=1),
                       df.iloc[:,i].shift(-1),
                       df['D'])
df
```

My question: Is this the expected behavior of np.where, even if columns A and B are not even called by their labels? Or did I make some mistake?

EDIT: Here is the long error message (I am using Jupyter)

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-184-2ac8fa635230> in <module>
      5     df['D'] = np.where(df.iloc[:,i] == df.min(axis=1),
      6                        df.iloc[:,i].shift(-1),
----> 7                        df['D'])
      8 df

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py in __setitem__(self, key, value)
   2936         else:
   2937             # set column
-> 2938             self._set_item(key, value)
   2939 
   2940     def _setitem_slice(self, key, value):

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py in _set_item(self, key, value)
   2999         self._ensure_valid_index(value)
   3000         value = self._sanitize_column(key, value)
-> 3001         NDFrame._set_item(self, key, value)
   3002 
   3003         # check if we are modifying a copy

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py in _set_item(self, key, value)
   3622 
   3623     def _set_item(self, key, value) -> None:
-> 3624         self._data.set(key, value)
   3625         self._clear_item_cache()
   3626 

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\internals\managers.py in set(self, item, value)
   1084         unfit_val_locs = []
   1085         removed_blknos = []
-> 1086         for blkno, val_locs in libinternals.get_blkno_placements(blknos, group=True):
   1087             blk = self.blocks[blkno]
   1088             blk_locs = blklocs[val_locs.indexer]

pandas\_libs\internals.pyx in get_blkno_placements()

pandas\_libs\internals.pyx in pandas._libs.internals.get_blkno_indexers()

ValueError: Buffer has wrong number of dimensions (expected 1, got 0)
```

Comment: Can't reproduce on pandas 1.1.0 and numpy 1.19.1. What versions do you have?

Comment: 1.0.1... I will try to update it.

Comment: Well, Anaconda is not letting me update to pandas 1.1.0, so I will just assume that it will go away when I finally update. If it doesn't, I will come back here and update the question with more info. Thanks for trying to replicate btw.

Answer (score 1):

`You cannot have two columns with same name` as if you would have a scenario like to merge columns A and C, then which column should be merged will give an error

Answer (score 0):

This is strange and I don't understand, but I did notice that the np.where is not relevant to the error. The below code has the same error. Must be something to do with assigning a column in a for loop? because outside the loop there is no problem.

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(10,3),columns=['A','A','C'])

df['D'] = np.random.randn(10,1)

for i in range(df.shape[1]-1):
    df['D'] = np.random.randn(10,1) #Breaks
```